# Order of Affine non-soluble groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-fields, affine-geometry

2-Transitive groups has been classified. The complete table has been mentioned in this [Textbook](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Permutation_Groups.html?id=4bNj8K1omGAC&redir_esc=y) ( see e.g., Table 7.3 and Table 7.4, page no. 194-197). Table 7.3 contains Affine 2-transitive groups and Table 7.4 contains Almost Simple 2-transitive groups.

**Question**

Consider only first 6 entries of the Table 7.3. Which groups out of these 6 are non-solvable ?

**Note** Refer [this](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Permutation_Groups.html?id=4bNj8K1omGAC&redir_esc=y)  for the definition of 2-transitive group and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) for the definition of solvable group.

Comment: I think you are asking too many questions at once here, and you should be asking about specific entries in the table. In any case the answer is easy in most cases. For example the groups in the first table entry contain ${\rm SL}(d,q)$, which is non-solvable when $d>1$ and $(d,q) \ne (2,2)$ or $(2,3)$. I think the only non-obvious case is when $q=81$ and $2^{1+4} \lhd H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt In that $q=81$ case, $H/2^{1+4}$ is a subgroup of $S_5$, and must contain an element of order $5$. Thus if it is $S_5$ or $A_5$ then the group is insoluble, and it is soluble otherwise.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes I had figured that out, but I was being cagy. I was hoping that the OP would formulate a more sensible question.

Comment: The first three and the sixth are clearly non-solvable except for some small values of $d$ and $q$, whereas the fourth is clearly solvable, so I don't know why you need to ask about those. David Craven has now answered the only non-obvious case, which if the fifth.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry to spoil your plan!

Comment: @DerekHolt, right it is trivial for the first three and the sixth cases. Now I understand that.  Thank you for the clarification.